Differential of mapping defined in projective space
First of all, English isn't my first language so sorry if my terminology is a bit off.
I'm asked to determine critical points $[p] \in \mathbb{RP}^n$ of a function $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{RP}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as the unique mapping (lifting, I think) such that $f = \tilde{f} \circ \pi$, where $\pi$ is the covering mapping $\pi: \mathbb{S}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^n$, and $f:\mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\displaystyle f(x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}) = \sum_{j = 0}^{n+1}jx_j^2$.
I know critical points are the points where $d\tilde{f}_{[p]}:T_{[p]}\mathbb{RP}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is 0 $\forall v \in T_{[p]}\mathbb{RP}^n$. Also, if we denote $A$ the antipode function (i.e. $A(p)=-p \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{S}^n$), $G  = \left\{ \text{id}, A\right\}$ is a subgroup of diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{S}^n$ and $\mathbb{RP}^n \cong \frac{\mathbb{S}^n}{G}$. Since $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism we have $T_{[p]}\mathbb{RP}^n \cong T_p\mathbb{S}^n \equiv L\{p\}^\perp$. Once here, I don't know how to use the information on $f$, like its differential $df_p$(which is perfectly computable), to get information on $d\tilde{f}_{\pi(p)}$ that allos me to conclude it's 0 for any $[p]$

Hint: Let $p\in S^n$ and $b=\pi(p)$ ('base point'). Then since $T\pi_p:T_p(S^n)\to T_b(\Bbb{RP}^n)$ is an isomorphism, we have that $b$ is a critical point for $\tilde{f}:\Bbb{RP}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ if and only if $p$ is a critical point for $f=\tilde{f}\circ \pi:S^n\to\Bbb{R}$. Why? Just write out how $df_p$ and $d\tilde{f}_b$ and $T\pi_p$ are related.

That makes sense, it is so easy but I couldn't see it haha.
Thanks.

It's the opposite of lifting. The point is that $f$ is invariant under  $G$ and hence descends to a smooth function on $\Bbb RP^n$.

You should write an answer to your own question to clear it from the unanswered queue.
